# Filtrar busqueda en textbox de listbox

Tags: c#

Necesito filtrar los datos que se muestran en un listbox. En un textbox escribo el numero que necesito, el problema es que en el listbox solo me muestra el valor cuando lo escribo igual, necesito que haga una busqueda que compare los numeros segun se escriba en el textbox, sin importar que los numeros lleven letras mayusculas o minisculas, la busqueda siempre se debe realizar.

De esta manera lo estaba haciendo en el evento text changed pero solo se cumple cuando es igual al numero del textbox:

```
lbPartes.Items.Clear();
  foreach (DataRow rw in fw.dtAllTable.Rows)
  {
  if (rw["Circuit"].ToString() == txtBuscar.Text)
  {
  lbPartes.Items.Add(rw["Circuit"].ToString());
  break;
  }
   }
  partRelCode = -1;
```

Comment: Convierte los textos a minusculas o mayusculas en la comprobación y así siempre coincidiran...

Answer (score 0):

Si no entendí mal tu duda, en lugar de `rw["Circuit"].ToString() == txtBuscar.Text` deberías utilizar

```
rw["Circuit"].ToString().Contains(txtBuscar.Text)
```

De esa manera, la condición se cumplirá sí en `rw["Circuit"]` contiene la cadena que escribas en el `TextBox`, no sólo en el caso de que sea igual

También tenés la posibilidad de utilizar `.StartsWith()` que funciona de la misma manera que un `.Contains()` pero sólo dará verdadero en caso de que el `string` comience por las letras tipeadas.

Saludos!

Comment: Si, solo que necesito que haya un movimiento en la lista, según vaya escribiendo en el textbox iran quedando solo los números que hacen coincidencia de acuerdo al textbox.